# Does sqlite have to be installed or can it be imported in code

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I want to write a small program that stores simple data. However the computer that this program will operate on is very secure. Installing anything on this system is out of the question. I was wondering if sqlite can be added as a library to a C application or any language not necessarily C. I assumed C/C++ would be easiest being compiled. I know it might not make much since because how can I run my application on this system but not install sqlite but this is the restraints that I am in. Any advice or resources will be very greatful.

Answer (score 2):

The sqlite library is available in many different forms. None of them require any sort of 'installation' to use.

https://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't believe I didn't find this myself. For some reason I kept running into sites that explain I need to install sqlite first before utilizing it. Thanks again.